# Modding Honda Ridgeline cigarette lighter to power USB ports

Tags: honda, wiring

I am doing a project in my '06 Ridgeline where I am taking out the iPod / Aux add-on and putting in a Bluetooth / Aux add-on at the back of the radio. In the process I will be removing the left cigarette lighter and replacing it was a USB and Aux port.

I've also been thinking about putting in some USB ports for charging and data transfer in the car and I figured that since I'll be taking the dash apart anyway, this is the perfect time to put those USB ports in.

I have chosen to put in a powered USB 3.0 hub which requires 12v. Therefore, I found an automotive DC to DC buck-boost regulator which is rated to output 12v at the appropriate wattage over the expected operating range of the vehicle's battery. Also, the input to the DC to DC buck-boost is appropriately fused. My idea was to take the now unused 12v outlet and wire it to my DC to DC regulator which ultimately powers my USB hub for glorious charging and data transfer.

**My question is this**: What is the connector at the back of the cigarette lighter and where can I buy a mating connector to make my own wiring harness that plugs into my DC to DC regulator? Alternatively what resources should I go to to find the information myself preferably without taking apart the dash.

Pardon me if this is the wrong forum.

UPDATE:
I have found a cigarette lighter replacement at the following link. I'm assuming I'm looking for the mating connector that fits the wiring shown on the left. It's unnumbered so I'm stuck again.

[image: Cigarette Lighter Assembly]
http://parts.sonshonda.com/showAssembly.aspx?ukey_product=1470290&ukey_assembly=275911

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally finished the project. I made a power cable using this part from Digikey and its working great.

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/42474-3/A27885CT-ND/456871?WT.v_sub=1717195&WT.mc_id=em_TEA1605A.US.Send&WT.z_email=7020_TEA1605A00US_tepurchasedpart&mkt_tok=eyJpIjoiWlROa05EYzRZVGMyTmpabSIsInQiOiJmUkFZeTlhTkcxRDA1ZXdvd1k0em9NRlEwdkR2TCs3NXFOaElRRU5naDlQdngwRzNlSlJUeVRiNHdjcDhaUWswczFRT2J1ZWt3Y0MxeDRJWXh3ZFlNZk11R0VTcytGT3N2Tk5OakgycTQ5OD0ifQ%3D%3D

Answer (score 5):

The power socket has a simple two cavity connector. It will most likely have #2 female spade connectors. Connect a new device with male spade connectors after first verifying polarity. I would not look for a matching connector, finding one is unlikely. I just take them apart and make a plan.

Drawing of power connector.

[image: Honda power socket]

It may not matter to your plans but note that this circuit is powered through a relay.

Answer (score 2):

You could just strip, solder and heatshrink the relevant cables together - should just be two, I'd guess. Quicker, easier, and less likely to break than trying to match the plug on the back of the 12v outlet. If you don't feel confident doing it yourself, an autoelectrician wouldn't take longer than 15minutes if the cables were all accessible and you drove the car to them.

Answer (score 1):

As stated before by Pete, I'd also recommend cutting or splicing the existing wires and adding your connections there. It'd be a lot easier and at times cheaper to do this as well.

I've done multiple mods on many cars, and have done this method and not one has failed. As long as you do your testing in Phases, e.g. connect two wires, test all is working then carry on.

You mentioned *"Data Transfer"* ? I'm not sure what data transfer you would get from USB charging other than perhaps the voltage.

There are also quite a few USB 12v DC chargers available which you can wire in directly to your 12V Cigarette lighter wiring, without having to add any DC to DC buck converters.

Comment: Using a USB hub means that I can sync my devices as well as charge them. If I had a straight up USB charger that plugged in to the cigarette lighter I would not be able to sync. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Oh right, sorry blonde moment with that :)